# How to check if a path is inside another path using Okio?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-native, okio

I am using Okio in Kotlin/Native and I would like to check if one path is inside another path.

Although there is a equal/greater than/less than operator, it looks like it only compares the length.

Example:

```
"/a/b/c/d".toPath().startsWith("/a/b/c".toPath()) // should return true
"/a/b/d/d".toPath().startsWith("/a/b/c".toPath()) // should return false
```

But startsWith does not exist.

Kotlin/JVM supports this via Java: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.io/java.io.-file/starts-with.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created this extension function which implements `startsWith` as described in the question:

```kotlin
fun Path.startsWith(other: Path) = normalized().run {
    other.normalized().let { normalizedOther ->
        normalizedOther.segments.size <= segments.size &&
                segments
                    .slice(0 until normalizedOther.segments.size)
                    .filterIndexed { index, s -> normalizedOther.segments[index] != s }
                    .isEmpty()
    }
}
```

It first checks if the `other` path has more segments (or components) than `this` path which would already mean they don't match since `/a/b/c` can never start with `/a/b/c/d` (or even `/1/2/3/4`).

If the segment count of `other` is the same or less, it proceeds with slicing `this` into as many segments as `other` has so that any sub-entries are ignored.

Then, it filters the sliced segments of `this` that don't match by using the same index for accessing the segments of `other`.

Now we have a list of segments that don't match on the same index. By checking if the list `isEmpty()`, we now have the conclusion of whether `this` startsWith `other` (you can turn this into an infix if you want.).

Passing test:

```
import okio.Path.Companion.toPath
import kotlin.test.Test
import kotlin.test.assertFalse
import kotlin.test.assertTrue

class PathsTests {

    @Test
    fun testStartsWith() {
        listOf(
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/b/c",
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/b/c/",
            "/A/B/C/D" to "/A/B/C",
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/b//c/",
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/b/../b/c",
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/../a/./b/../b///c",
            "\\a\\b\\c\\d" to "/a/../a/./b/../b///c",
            "/home/user/.config/test" to "/home/user",
            "/var/www/html/app" to "/var/www/html",
            "/home/user" to "/",
            "/" to "/",
            "////////////////////////" to "/",
            "/" to "////////////////////////",
            "/home/user" to "/home/user",
            "/home/user/./" to "/home/user",
            "/home/user" to "/home/user/./",
            "/./var" to "/var",
            "." to ".",
            "./" to ".",
            ".." to "..",
            "../.." to "../..",
            "./.." to "../.",
            "../." to "./..",
            "./../." to ".././.",
            "/." to "/.",
            "./" to ".",
            "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z" to "/a/b/c",
            "/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a" to "/a/a/a"
        ).forEach { (pathString, otherPathString) ->
            assertTrue(
                pathString.toPath().startsWith(otherPathString.toPath()),
                "$pathString should start with $otherPathString"
            )
        }

        listOf(
            "/a/b/c" to "/a/b/c/d/",
            "/a/b/c/" to "/a/b/c/d",
            "/a/b/d/d" to "/a/b/c",
            "/a/b/d/d" to "/a/b/ce",
            "/a/b/ce" to "/a/b/c",
            "/a/b/c" to "/a/b/ce",
            "/abcd" to "/a/b/c/d",
            "/a/../b/c" to "/a/b/c",
            "/a/b/" to "/a/b//c",
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/b/../c",
            "/a/b/c/d" to "/a/./a/../b/./b///c",
            "/a/b/c" to "/c/b/a",
            "/a/a/a/a" to "/a/a/a/a/a",
            "\\a\\b\\d\\d" to "\\a\\b\\c",
            "\\a\\b\\d\\d" to "/a/b/c",
            "/home/user/.config/test" to "/home/user2",
            "/var/www/html/app" to "/var/local/www/html/app",
            "/home/user" to ".",
            "/" to "./",
            "/home/user" to "/home/user2",
            "/home/user/./" to "/home/user2",
            "/home/user2" to "/home/user/./",
            "../var" to "/var",
            "." to "..",
            "./" to "..",
            ".." to ".",
            "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z" to "/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/r/s/t/u/z",
            "/a/a/a" to "/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a",
            "/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a/a" to "/A",
        ).forEach { (pathString, otherPathString) ->
            assertFalse(
                pathString.toPath().startsWith(otherPathString.toPath()),
                "$pathString should not start with $otherPathString"
            )
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you know how to join okio.Path without applying the separator character manually?

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov Just use `/` as Okio Path overloads the div operator. `path1 / path2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could `.toString()` the `Path`s to do this operation.

You could otherwise use `relativeTo` and check the result. That's not exhaustively correct but something like the following could be a start:

```kotlin
  @Test fun testingInclusion() {
    println("/a/b/c/d".toPath().contains("/a/b/c".toPath()))
    println("/a/b/d/d".toPath().contains("/a/b/c".toPath()))
  }

  private fun Path.contains(other: Path): Boolean {
    return !this.relativeTo(other).toString().contains("..")
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I was thinking about doing it using `relativeTo` but I thought this is a bit hacky. Using direct string comparison on the full path is hard to get exactly right and handle all edge cases (a naive implementation could fail with "/a/b/cc".startsWith("/a/b/c")). It would probably be most correct to check if every path component of `/a/b/c` is the same as `/a/b/c/d` up to the length of `/a/b/c`. This is what I have implemented right now and I'll post it as a separate answer.